# What is the size of turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make a program as small as possible (Including the dependencies) and I cant find a way how to find the size of turtle.

Edit:
I tried looking for the package size on PyPi but I could not find it.

Comment: Even with the hint about dependencies, "small program" is still completely ambiguous. Are you talking about the turtle pen-width? Lines of code? Number of installed dependencies vs dependencies included with Python? Is this a deployment question?

Comment: "size" is a bit vague.  What exactly are you trying to optimize for?  Are you talking about the size of a standalone executable after you've built a package with all the dependencies compiled in, or the size of the space that the module takes up on disk in a normal Python installation after someone's done `pip install -r requirements.txt` or similar, or the size of the *download* for the aforementioned install, or...?  Note that the answers to some of those might depend on platform, packaging method, and other variables.

Comment: All that I am trying to do is get the size of the dependency (For instance numpy is ~15MB).

Comment: Please provide more information about your use case. Why does this matter?

Comment: I'm just doing this for a personal project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's around 140.3 KiB in python 3.9.

You can find the file and so the size of it in your files in:

```
/lib/python3.9#Replace the *3.9* with your python version.
```

But for it to work you also need a lot of other python modules e.g. tkinter and that's another 709 KiB already.